# Understanding of syntax's NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm studying tutorial concerning Core Data, and I'm confused about lines of following code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

As i know NSFetchedResultSectionInfo is protocol, but protocol is a list of methods defined in header of class. Im not understand whats going on here, what meaning of double square brackets `[..][..];` ?

Maybe it is new modern syntax of objective-c i didn't know, it would be nice if somebody could explain this clearer for me, thank you.

Comment: [Name of the array - has brackets as well because the returned value is an array)][objectIndex]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo` means in this case, that the result of

```
[self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];

// ->

NSArray *sections = [self.fetchedResultsController sections]; // array of objects, that confirm <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>
// sections[section] is same as [sections objectAtIndex:section]
```

is a class, that confirms to the protocol `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`

so the call `[sectionInfo numberOfObjects];` will be interpreted by the compiler as valid ;)

Comment: I understand how it suppose to work and what output will be, but I'm not completely understand how can i use protocol as class? Isn't protocol just bunch of methods/properties?

Comment: it is, but what is an `id`? its just like a `var`, without any special content. it can be everything. But you need a class, that confirms to the protocol `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`. So in your declaration you tell that your sectionInfo of type id, doesn't matter what class it is, confirms to the protocol, so you can use the methods defined there ;) You should read some tutorials and create protocols yourself, so you can better understand.

Comment: If i understand correct, you want to tell me that sectionInfo is only a variable the conforms to protocol defined in triangle brackets, not the protocol itself? My question may sound stupid but its first time i see syntax like that one.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` means array of `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` objects here.

So, every bracket is equal to an `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` object.